# How can I get mathbb version of small "e"?

Tags: symbols

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to look up a symbol?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol)

If I write `$\mathbb{e}$` nothing gets displayed. However here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackboard_bold it says that blackboard style letter "e" exists in Latex. How can I type it?

Comment: Try [`bbm`](http://ctan.org/pkg/bbm), and then `\mathbbm{e}`. See the [LaTeX Comprehensive Symbol List](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) (Table 213, p 68).

Comment: Duplicate: [How to look up a symbol?](http://goo.gl/NjJCc)